# Google Maps API: find a main route/Alternate route between two points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the main route between two locations. I have found out the distance and duration but I want to get the main route like in following image I want to get "via 1-57 S". I tried following the code to get directions but I got too many of them; I want only one suggested direction circled in an image.

For example:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
    {
        alert("Root length: "+result.routes.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < result.routes.length; i++)
        {       
            var dur = result.routes[i].legs[0].distance.value/1000;     
            var steps = result.routes[i].legs[0].steps;  
            for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                var nextSegment = steps[j].instructions;
                alert("nextSegment: " + nextSegment + " path latlong: "+steps[j].path);
            }   

            var hours = Math.floor((result.routes[i].legs[0].duration.value)/3600);
            var minutes = Math.ceil(((result.routes[i].legs[0].duration.value) - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        }        
    }
});
```

Image:

[Example image to find main route(circled in image) to reach destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcjE2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "via route x" is in each route object `summary` (without the word "via" but you can add that by yourself).

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

        var routes = response.routes;

        for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++) {

            // Display the routes summary in a div
            document.getElementById('routes').innerHTML += 'Via ' + routes[i].summary + '<br />';
        }
    }
});
```

Below is a (quite complex) example on how to get each route details and display them on the map.

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/v9e36ssg/1/)</kbd>